# Regex to select text after second occurance of special character

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following text:

```
/sources/x1/y1/CLD_strict_AccountsMatchfile_feed_2015062405.txt
/sources/x1/y1/CLD_strict_AdGroupMatchFile_feed_2015062405.txt
/sources/x1/y1/CLD_strict_AdsMatchfile_feed_2015062405.txt
/sources/x1/y1/CLD_strict_AdvertisersMatchfile_feed_2015062405.txt
/sources/x1/y1/CLD_strict_AudienceMatchFile_feed_2015062405.txt
```

And would like to match on everything after the 2nd "_" and before "Matchfile" using bash.

So for example:

- on line 1 I want to select "Accounts"
- on line 2 I want to select AdGroup

etc.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked how to do it using bash:
`${line%%Match[Ff]ile*}` will remove everything after and including Matchfile, and `${line##*_}` will remove everything before the last underscore. So you can loop through the text like:

```
$ while read line; do line=${line%%Match[Ffile]*}; line=${line##*_}; echo $line; done < filename
Accounts
AdGroup
Ads
Advertisers
Audience
```

Answer (score 2):

In case you hadn't noticed some of these have Matchfile and some MatchFile, assuming wither is applicable as the end of the group you want to match the following perl one liner will work

```
perl -pe 's/^.*_.*_(.*)Match[Ff]ile.*$/$1/'
```

eg

```
find /sources/x1/y1/ -type f -name "*.txt" |  perl -pe 's/^.*_.*_(.*)Match[Ff]ile.*$/$1/'
```

will print

```
Accounts
AdGroup
Ads
Advertisers
Audience
```

(if the above are the only files in that dir which end in .txt)

Answer (score 2):

```
cut -d'_' -f2- text-file | grep -oP "(?<=_).*(?=Match[Ff]ile)"
```

This uses lookbehind and lookahead regex to find but not match what's in the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

With sed:

```
cat filename|sed 's/^[^_]\+_[^_]\+_\(.*\)Match[fF]ile.*/\1/g'
```

or with grep (on linux where grep supports -P and -o)

```
cat filename|grep -o -P "^[^_]+_[^_]+_\K(.*)(?=Match[fF]ile)"
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done easily using `awk`:

```
awk -F 'Match[Ff]ile|_' '{print $3}' file
Accounts
AdGroup
Ads
Advertisers
Audience
```